# What is the recommended Application Server for Playframework 2.x deployment?

Tags: java, scala, jboss, playframework, playframework-2.0

I planned to use `jBoss` to deploy, manage and monitor playframework applications, but from https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin/wiki/ConfigurationLoggingJBoss7, I found jBoss and playframework doesn't play very well together.

From the [official documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Production), it only says Apache or Nginx can be used for HTTP server, but no application server is mentioned there. Does anyone have ideas about what would be a suiable application server for Playframework deployment? How about [Apache Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) or [GlassFish](https://glassfish.java.net/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need any application server to run a Play 2.x application. The application can run stand alone, it internally uses Netty to handle the sockets, Akka to handle the concurrency etc.

Usually Apache or Nginx are used in front of a Play application to offload serving of static resources, HTTPS handling (both can be done directly in the application itself) and above all to allow public access to multiple applications on the same IP and port under different paths.

Comment: I know application server is not necessary.. but instead of writing script of `activator run` to start/stop multiple version of applications (dev-1, dev-2, testing), maybe manage them all in one place, such as an application server, would be more convinient..

Comment: Moreover, an application server can output logs and running status for each running instance in it Web UI, which I really love.

Comment: I think that the structure of a Play 2 application with Netty, Akka etc. makes it quite difficult to make it JavaEE compliant. I am not familiar too much with the monitoring abilities of the Play2 application, perhaps you can find out more [here](http://typesafe.com/products/typesafe-reactive-platform)

Answer (score 0):

In Play 1.0 you could build to a war to run in a container like you describe. This feature was removed in Play 2.0 to promote the embedded Netty server as the main way to deploy applications.  Now you need the [play2war](https://github.com/play2war/play2-war-plugin) to achieve this functionality.